# Alertify confirm box is not displayed with functioning css on hover

Tags: jquery, css, alert, alertify

I have just implemented [Alertify](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/) in my Rails application (implemented through the `gem "alertify-rails"`), but can't get the css to look as it should. I am new to css, so don't have many ideas about how to start on trying to fix this. Has anyone had the same experience? I don't have much css in my application, so I don't think that there are css conflicts.

[image]

Here is how it should look:

[image]

The code I am using to trigger the confirm box:

```
alertify.prompt("Message", function (e, str) {
  if (e) {
    // user clicked "ok"
  } else {
    // user clicked "cancel"
  }
}, "Default Value");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Get FireBug for Firefox and inspect that button.  Compare it to the working demo. What you're looking for is markup as well as CSS comparison - you'll figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Hi check this below code.. this will help you

```
$("#btn").live("click", function () {
 alertify.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?", function (asc) {
     if (asc) {
         //ajax call for delete       
         alertify.success("Record is deleted.");

     } else {
         alertify.error("You've clicked cancel");
     }
 }, "Default Value");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but that does not seem to fix the problem.